# .includes (or any other methos I apply) is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having an object with the following structure and a piece of JavaScript code to transform the .duration of that object, originally a string, into a number with its corresponding minutes:

```js
let movies = [
    {
      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Frank Darabont",
      "duration": "2h 22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.3
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather",
      "year": 1972,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "2h",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.2
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
      "year": 1974,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
    }
];


function turnHoursToMinutes(arr) {
    return arr
        .slice(0, arr.length)
        .map(movie => {
            if (movie.duration.includes('h')) {
                const durationArr = movie.duration.split(/\D+/).map(item => Number(item));
                durationArr[0] *= 60;
                movie.duration = durationArr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);
                return movie;
            }   
            movie.duration = Number(movie.duration.slice(0,2));
            return movie
        });
};

console.log(turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(movies !== turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies)[0].duration === 'number');
```

When I execute the code, the program returns me an error (displayed in the last 3 console.logs) saying that the first method I pass inside .map is not a function. I've been a couple of days looking at this and I still don't know what might be causing this issue. The worst thing is that it actually prints the result correctly :/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: After the first iteration, `movie.duration` is a number, not a string. numbers do not have an `.includes` method.

Comment: This happens because you have object values in the array, and `Array#slice` only performs a shallow copy. Thus, you are modifying your source movie objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens as you are mutating the `duration` property in the source `movie` object.

After the first run of `turnHoursToMinutes` the `movie.duration` is no longer a `string` but a `number`, which don't have a `includes` function in its `prototype`.

This is the line, which is mutating the `duration` property:

```
movie.duration = Number(movie.duration.slice(0,2));
```

Try to make a copy of the `movie` object and then apply the transformation:

```js
let movies = [
    {
      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Frank Darabont",
      "duration": "2h 22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.3
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather",
      "year": 1972,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "2h",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.2
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
      "year": 1974,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
    }
];


function turnHoursToMinutes(arr) {
    return arr
        .slice(0, arr.length)
        .map(movie => {
            const updatedMovie = {...movie};
            if (updatedMovie.duration.includes('h')) {
                const durationArr = updatedMovie.duration.split(/\D+/).map(item => Number(item));
                durationArr[0] *= 60;
                updatedMovie.duration = durationArr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);
                return updatedMovie;
            }   
            updatedMovie.duration = Number(movie.duration.slice(0,2));
            return updatedMovie
        });
};

console.log(turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(movies !== turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies)[0].duration === 'number');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `movie.duration` to a Number the first time you call `turnHoursToMinutes`, on the second call to the function you're getting the error, because `Number` does not have an `.includes` function.

One way to fix this is to return a copy of the movie object using `Object.assign` to create a clone of the movie inside your map function, then modify that copy and return it, hence creating an array of new objects with the modified duration property.

Below is a copy of your snippet with just one line added to make it work:

```js
let movies = [
    {
      "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
      "year": 1994,
      "director": "Frank Darabont",
      "duration": "2h 22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.3
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather",
      "year": 1972,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "2h",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "rate": 9.2
    },
    {
      "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
      "year": 1974,
      "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
      "duration": "22min",
      "genre": [
        "Crime",
        "Drama"
      ],
    }
];


function turnHoursToMinutes(arr) {
    return arr
        .slice(0, arr.length)
        .map(movie => {
            movie = Object.assign({}, movie);
            if (movie.duration.includes('h')) {
                const durationArr = movie.duration.split(/\D+/).map(item => Number(item));
                durationArr[0] *= 60;
                movie.duration = durationArr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);
                return movie;
            }   
            movie.duration = Number(movie.duration.slice(0,2));
            return movie
        });
};

console.log(turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(movies !== turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
console.log(typeof turnHoursToMinutes(movies)[0].duration === 'number');
```